# How to call an JInternalFrame from an outside JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I've created two separate java files, DesktopSample and GUIdemo. I want DesktopSample--which contains the Main Jframe--to call the JINternalFrame in the other GUIdemo when a button is clicked. What code should I use to do this? I use this code on my GUIdemo where my JINternalFrame is located.

```
   import javax.swing.*; 
   import java.awt.*; 
   import java.awt.event.*; 
   public class GUIdemo extends JInternalFrame implements ActionListener{

  JLabel lbldept1 = new JLabel("Department 1"); 
  JLabel lbldept2 = new JLabel("Department 2"); 
  JLabel lbldept3 = new JLabel("Department 3"); 
  JLabel lbldept4 = new JLabel("Department 4");

 JTextField txtdept1 = new JTextField(10); 
 JTextField txtdept2= new JTextField(10);
 JTextField txtdept3= new JTextField(10); 
 JTextField txtdept4 = new JTextField(10);

 JButton btnView= new JButton("View Chart"); 
 JButton btnReset = new JButton("Reset"); 
 JFrame JFParentFrame; 
 JDesktopPane desktop; 
 JPanel panel1;

 public GUIdemo(JFrame getParentFrame) {

 super("Record of Units Manufactured",true,true,true,true);
 setSize(200,300);
 JFParentFrame = getParentFrame; 
 panel1 = new JPanel(); 
 panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));

 panel1.add(lbldept1); 
 panel1.add(txtdept1);
 panel1.add(lbldept2); 
 panel1.add(txtdept2); 
 panel1.add(lbldept3); 
 panel1.add(txtdept3); 
 panel1.add(lbldept4); 
 panel1.add(txtdept4); 
 panel1.add(btnView);
 panel1.add(btnReset);
 btnView.addActionListener(this); 
 btnReset.addActionListener(this);

 setVisible(true); }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
 if(e.getSource()==btnView){ 
 int num1 = Integer.parseInt(txtdept1.getText()); 
 int num2 = Integer.parseInt(txtdept2.getText()); 
 int num3 = Integer.parseInt(txtdept3.getText()); 
 int num4 = Integer.parseInt(txtdept4.getText());
 } 
 else if (e.getSource()==btnReset){ 
 txtdept1.setText(""); 
 txtdept2.setText("");
 txtdept3.setText("");
 txtdept4.setText("");

 } 
 }

 }
```

And here is my DesktopSample code:

```
  import javax.swing.*;   
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*; 
  public class DesktopSample extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

  JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane(); 
  Container con = getContentPane();

  JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
  JMenu ManufacturingPlant = new JMenu("Manufacturing Plant");
  JMenuItem Record = new JMenuItem("Record Units Manufactured"); 
  JMenuItem Exit = new JMenuItem("Exit Application");
  JButton btniframe = new JButton("Inside the frame");

  public DesktopSample() { 
  con.add(desktop); 
  setJMenuBar(bar); 
  bar.add(ManufacturingPlant); 
  ManufacturingPlant.add(Record);
  ManufacturingPlant.add(Exit); 
  Record.addActionListener(this); 
  Exit.addActionListener(this);

 setSize(300,300); 
 setTitle("OOP Final Exam");
 setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
 setVisible(true); 
 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
 if(e.getSource()==Record){ 
 //what code should be put here in order to call the GUIdemo Internal Frame 
 } 
 else if(e.getSource()==btniframe){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Hey!!! You clicked me!!");
 } 
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 DesktopSample d = new DesktopSample();
 } 
 }
```

It tells me an error that it requires a Jframe and that there is no arugments, I kinda think that it is because of this "public GUIdemo(JFrame getParentFrame)" but I dont know how to make the arguments for this to show.

Comment: If you make the JInternalFrame public in GUIdemo then DesktopSample can call it.

Comment: How do I make it public? isn't it already declared public?

Comment: You need to post a little more code so we can see what you've done. By default member variables are private.

Comment: @mttdbrd I have post all my codes for you to see, that is the only code missing in my little program.

Comment: I wish the guy who had posted an answer earlier and deleted it still had his comment here because it turns out he was right. You need to look at this tutorial. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

Comment: what I dont get is I can call the JInternalFrame if this wasn't on my code "public GUIdemo(JFrame getParentFrame)", but if it isn't there it gives me a lot of errors.